# Does a list<> store a reference to the property or instance?

Tags: c#, .net, list, reference

When adding to a list, if I add the property of a class instance, is it set to a reference of the property's value or a reference to the property?

Example:

If I have:

```
class A {
     public Action<Guid> SomeDelegate { get; set; }
}
```

And in a different class I create an instance of class A, ie:

```
class B {
     public B() {
          a = new A();
          a.SomeDelegate = someFunction;
          List<Action<Guid>> myList = new List<Action<Guid>>;
          myList.Add(a.SomeDelegate);
          a.SomeDelegate = anotherFunction;
      }
}
```

What will be in `myList`? A reference to `anotherFunction` or a reference to `someFunction`?

If it is a reference to `someFunction`, how would I go about making it a reference to `anotherFunction`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the List would continue to hold a reference to a delegate instance pointing to SomeFunction.

The low-tech solution to achieving what you want to achieve would be to wrap the delegate inside another object. Add this object to the list; you are then free to mutate the wrapper object, change its property to the new value.
At the point where you consume the delegates in the list, instead of directly invoking the delegate, use `wrapperInstance.Delegate(params)`

**Update**: I think my response wasn't clear from Jason's comment.

```
class B
    {
        List<A> myList;
        public B() {
          var a = new A();
          a.SomeDelegate = ( x => Console.WriteLine("SomeFunction " + x) );
          myList = new List<A>();
          myList.Add(a);               // add wrapper object instead of delegate to list
            SerialInvokeDelegates();   // will invoke SomeFunction

          a.SomeDelegate = (x => Console.WriteLine("AnotherFunction " + x));
            SerialInvokeDelegates();   // will invoke AnotherFunction
        }

        private void SerialInvokeDelegates()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoking all delegates in B's List");
            foreach (var a in myList)
                a.SomeDelegate(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The class `A` is already a wrapper around the delegate. Just use that.

Answer (score 4):

The single item in your list will be a reference to `someFunction`.

Think of like this:

You have an instance of `A`. Now `A` has a property called `SomeDelegate`. You have a references `someFunction` and `anotherFunction` to delegates that I will also call `someFunction` and `anotherFunction` respectively in the pictures below. So the picture is this:

```
a local to B constructor
---------------
|             |
|SomeDelegate-----------> someFunction
|             |           anotherFunction
---------------
```

Now you add `a.SomeDelegate` to `myList`. So the picture is this:

```
a local to B constructor
---------------
|             |
|SomeDelegate-----------> someFunction <-------myList[0]
|             |           anotherFunction
---------------
```

Now you come along and change `SomeDelegate` to refer to `anotherFunction`. Now the picture is this:

```
a local to B constructor
---------------
|             |
|SomeDelegate-----|       someFunction <-------myList[0]
|             |   |-----> anotherFunction
---------------
```

This should make it clear that `myList[0]` still refers to `someFunction` and why.

Now, if you want `myList` to see the changes, the best easiest way is to make it a list of `A`.

```
 A a = new A();
 a.SomeDelegate = someFunction;
 List<A> myList = new List<A>();
 myList.Add(a);
 a.SomeDelegate = anotherFunction;
```

Now it will be the case that `myList[0].SomeDelegate` refers to `anotherFunction`. You can easily extract the actions like so:

```
 var actions = myList.Select(x => x.SomeDelegate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A list of a class type will hold references to outside objects.  Anything that happens to an object to which the list happens to hold a reference, will happen to the object referred to by the list (since the object to which the list holds a reference is the object referred to by the list).

Note that lists of structure types behave differently.  If a list holds a structure type, the only way to make any change to a structure therein is to create a new instance of the structure, reflecting the desired changes, and store it to the list.  For example:

```
  List<Point> myList = ...; // Initialize it somehow
  Point tempPt = myList[4];
  tempPt.X = 19;
  myList[4] = tempPt;
```

While it would be possible to design a generic container-of-struct which would expose some other means of acting on structs contained therein (e.g.

```
  myContainer.ActOnItem(4, (ref Point pt) => {pt.X = 19;});
```

none of the container types built into .net provide any such functionality.